# printing indexof object as id of html element in knockout js

Tags: html, knockout.js

In the below code I need to give index of the loop as Id of the html input element

```
                    <input type="text" data-bind="text:Value">
```

I tried data-bind="text: $index" , but i cant set it as Id attribute. Anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set the id of the element, try:

```
data-bind="attr: {id: $index}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `input` element. Try to use [value](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) instead of `text` binding like that:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: $index">
```